# Skeleton Screen or Loading Animation

Tags: web, loading

I'm designing a loading screen for a website application. I'm having two options for this:

- Skeleton Screen
- Loading Animation

I haven't known how to choose one of them yet due to some reasons:

1. I can't find any article that argue about using Skeleton Screen.
2. There're many things need to consider when designing loading animation: UI Copy, Animation, Brand Identity.

Therefore, I can't decide which one is better than other yet. Hope to learn something today :D Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

here is an article about how design skeleton https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a

Comment: You should quote relevant parts of the website you linked because links might stop working and content become unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a

Its compared and explained in this article. Seems skeleton screen is a bit better than classic animations.

One of the idea could be also that you use both. So skeleton tree that has animated bars somehow..